# How to properly validate form using jquery Unobtrusive Validation?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to use jquery unobtrusive validation in my form, and no matter if the html inputs are empty or not, the validation message is always showing as soon as I open the page. The HTML is in a handlebars template. I am using HttpPost to retrieve data when loading the page.

My View:

```
    <form id="submitForm" class="form">
        <section id="conferenceContainer"></section>
        <div id="saveBtnContainer">
            <input type="submit" id="saveBtn" class="btn" value="Submit" />
            <div id="lblCheckContainer">
                <label id="lblCheck"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="conferenceTemplate">
    <div id="newConference">
        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ConferenceTitle,
                                new { @class="confLabels" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ConferenceTitle,
                                  new { @id="confTitle", @class="form-control", @Value= "{{ConferenceTitle}}" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ConferenceTitle, "*Enter a conference title*", new { @class="text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EventDate,
                                new { @class="confLabels" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EventDate,
                                   new { @id="confDate", @class="form-control", @Value="{{formatDate EventDate}}" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EventDate, "*Enter the date of the conference*", new { @class="text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RegFullPrice,
                                new { @class="confLabels" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RegFullPrice,
                                   new { @id="confPrice", @class="form-control", @Value="{{RegFullPrice}}" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RegFullPrice, "*Enter the price to register for conference*", new { @class="text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PreRegEndDate,
                                new { @class="confLabels" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PreRegEndDate,
                                   new { @id= "confPreRegDate", @class="form-control", @Value= "{{formatDate PreRegEndDate}}" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PreRegEndDate, "*Enter the last day to pre-register for conference*", new { @class="text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PreRegDiscount,
                                new { @class="confLabels" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PreRegDiscount,
                                   new { @id= "confPreRegDiscount", @class="form-control", @Value= "{{PreRegDiscount}}" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PreRegDiscount, "*Enter the discount for pre-registration*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I am handling the submit input in .ready function where 'saveData()' is a method with the ajax call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var setup = new ConferenceSetup();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setup.GetData();

        $('#submitForm').submit(function () {
            var confirmSave = confirm("Are you finished editing the Conference?");

            if (confirmSave) {
                setup.SaveData();
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It seems I have the server side validation working but I cannot get the client side to act like I want.

My model:

```
    [DisplayName("Conference Title")]
    [Required]
    public string ConferenceTitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Event Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Registration Price")]
    [Range(0, 999.99, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between $0 and $1,000")]
    [Required]
    public decimal RegFullPrice { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Pre-Registration End Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime PreRegEndDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Pre-Registration Discount")]
    [Range(0, 999.99, ErrorMessage = "Discount must be between $0 and $1,000")]
    [Required]
    public decimal PreRegDiscount { get; set; }
```

My Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class ConfSetupController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NewConf()
    {
        ConferenceModel model = new ConferenceModel();

        return View(model);
    }
```

This is what my page looks like, the validation messages never go away

[image]

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: To get to this page are you using a GET or POST?

Comment: I am using POST

Comment: @nativeAndoidCodes can you post your controller?

Comment: Edited to show controller. Also, I meant I was using post on my API. I am not using anything on my controller

Comment: I don't think I know enough about handlebars to be super helpful here.  What does your setup.GetData() function do?

Comment: No problem. It just does an ajax call to retrieve the data from the api. The api is getting data from the database, that data is used to populate the input fields on the page if there is any data.Handlebars is simply placing that data in those input fields.

Comment: @nativeAndoidCodes do you still get the validation messages if you skip that GetData function?

Comment: If I skip that function, then basically nothing on the page is rendered because of Handlebars. I will just have empty containers with no inputs.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the validation on page load check if .field-validation-error and .validation-summary-valid css class "display" property is set to "none".